# 2D Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I'm trying to make a 2D array that looks like:

```
----
----
----
----
```

For the life of my I can't figure it, I'm new to C++. 
Here are my attempts so far:

```
    char board[boardSize][boardSize];
    for(int i=0;i<boardSize;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<boardSize;j++){
            board[i][j]='-';
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<boardSize;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<boardSize;j++){
            cout<<board[i][j];
        }
    }
```

This gives:

```
----------------
```

Can anyone please direct me in the right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<boardSize;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<boardSize;j++){
        cout<<board[i][j];
    }
}
```

should be

```
for(int i=0;i<boardSize;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<boardSize;j++){
        cout<<board[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

you're printing all the "lines" on one line.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I should have seen such an easy mistake.